# mongo query and project based on key names

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i need to query all marvel saves:

accepted result:

```
 hero__marvel__avangers: {saves: Object};
 hero__marvel__xmen: {saves: Object};
```

from document:

```
 _id:606310cfeaf16c5f666f37d5
 id:"2020"
 ver:4
 hero__marvel__avangers:Object         
   saves: Object, 
   kills: Object,
   loses: Object
 hero__marvel__xmen:Object
   saves: Object, 
   kills: Object,
   loses: Object
 hero__dc__justic_leage: Object
   saves: Object, 
   kills: Object,
   loses: Object
```

in sort i'm looking for some way to first choose only keys which are /marvel/ and then project

something along the lines of doing:

```
{
   '$project': {
        'hero__marvel__avengers.saves': 1
   }
}
```

only dynamically since i do not want to specify each marvel hero in my projection

thanks

Comment: Can you post some documents from the collection and expected result.

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION #1**: If you want the result to be in single document.

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            array: {
                $filter: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
                    as: "item",
                    cond: {
                        $regexMatch: {
                            input: "$$item.k",
                            regex: ".*marvel.*",
                            options: "i"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
        }
    }
]);
```

[Solution #1 in Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iTMldCn8KsL).

Output:

```js
{
    "hero__marvel__avangers" : {
        "name" : "Iron Man"
    },
    "hero__marvel__xmen" : {
        "name" : "Professor X"
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION #2**: If you want the result to be in separate document.

1. Convert the document into array of format `{ k: "", v: "" }` using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/).
2. `$unwind` the resulting array.
3. Match the required field using [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).
4. Convert it back to object using [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/).

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            array: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$array" },
    {
        $match: {
            "array.k": {
                $regex: ".*marvel.*",
                $options: "i"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: [["$array"]]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Solution #2 in Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vbVk1kipq_d).

Output

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "hero__marvel__avangers" : {
        "name" : "Iron Man"
    }
},

/* 2 */
{
    "hero__marvel__xmen" : {
        "name" : "Professor X"
    }
}
```

Testdata:

```js
[
    {
        hero__marvel__avangers: { name: "Iron Man" },
        hero__marvel__xmen: { name: "Professor X" },
        hhero__dc__justic_leage: { name: "Bat man" }
    }
]
```